# Laravel 5.2 - How to return a PDF as part of a JSON response

Tags: php, json, laravel, pdf

So I have developed an API and one of the endpoints is a report generator. Normally they send in the name of the report and some other variables and it pops out a PDF using [Laravel-Snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy).

I am also using [JWT-Auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) for authentication. Since I need to be HIPAA compliant I will be refreshing the token on EVERY call. For most endpoints this is easy as I just add it to the meta of my json response.

However, for the reports they only return a PDF with headers to force download etc. Is there a way for me to send the PDF data as part of a JSON response that applications hitting this API would be able to use? Do I maybe need to encrypt it in some way that it can be sent with a json response? Any other ideas on any line of thought would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try use `file_get_content` and send content as part of a json?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never had to do this personally, but the way I've seen it in APIs is to read the file contents, base64 encode and serve that up in the json response.

Quick bit of code

```
$pdf = base64_encode(file_get_contents('path/to/my.pdf'));

return response()->json([
    'pdf' => $pdf,
]);
```

The user can then consume this as such.

```
$pdf = base64_decode($json->pdf);

file_put_contents('path/to/save/my.pdf', $pdf);
```

You should then be able to open/read the saved file as normal.

Comment: awesome thanks. I will try this out and if it works I will mark it as the answer

Comment: I have put this into action and it works. I had to tweak some things on angularjs's side to make it use the data out of the json response but it didn't take long. Total of .3 seconds added to response time

Answer (score 1):

I think sending large binary data as part of JSON response is not the best idea. I would rather create temporary GET URI for PDF file with uuid or maybe more meaningful id and present it in actual JSON response. API consumer will be able to read the response and download a file.

Comment: We have considered this but we will be in a SaaS environment and need to be HIPAA compliant which means that even if the files are available for only a few seconds they are still available and putting in checks to make sure that the correct person / client is accessing this temporary file is way more headache then the couple of extra seconds adding the binary data to the json response will create.

Comment: You can generate random string in file's access URL that cannot be guessed and give that URL is API response. That way the file will not be accessible outside.

Comment: honestly way too much work to avoid a few seconds. It's a good idea, just not what im looking for.